# Code crashes when trying to set a localized description for an NSError

Tags: objective-c, ios, nserror

I'm trying to set error message if something is wrong, but I get

```
This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key NSLocalizedDescription
```

Here is the code I use

```
-(id)getMoneyFromAccount:(int) sum error:(NSError **)error
{
    if(self.balance - sum < 0)
    {
        NSDictionary *details = [NSDictionary dictionary];
        [details setValue:@"You don't have enough money" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"money" code:200 userInfo:details];
        return nil;
    }
    self.balance = self.balance - sum;
    return  [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.balance];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling `setValue:forKey:` where you should be calling `setObject:forKey:`

```
[details setObject:@"You don't have enough money" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
```

In addition, you have to change from `NSDictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary` or set the values in the initializer:

```
NSDictionary *details = [NSDictionary
    dictionaryWithObject:@"You don’t…"
    forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
```

The `setValue:forKey:` would work with a mutable dictionary, but it’s better to call `setObject:forKey:` directly.

Comment: When I change the code as you suggest I get "NSDictionary may not respond to setObject:forKey"

Comment: Yes, I missed that you used an ordinary, immutable dictionary. I’ve edited the answer, now the code has to work.

Answer (score 1):

When you need change localizedDescription for NSError which is initalized, you can override NSError class, like this:

```
@interface ValidationError : NSError

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *localizedDescription;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, setValue: forKey: is the right method to use. Maybe this is because you need to create NSMutableDictionary instead of NSDictionary.

Comment: Not with an NSDictionary (immutable)

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying? You can always get a NSDictionary with [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableDictionary]; from mutable dictionary.

Comment: He’s responding to your first sentence, `NSDictionary` won’t respond to `setValue:forKey:` with the `NSLocalizedDescription` key.

Comment: @Ganzolo: correct, I didn't read the second one.  However, your statement is also incorrect because you should be using setObject:ForKey:

Comment: Why? NSLocalizedDescription is NSString. setValue forKey take NSStrings for the key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSMutableDictionary or an initialiser to set the value.  NSDictionary can't be changed once you have initialised it.

```
NSDictionary* details = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"..." 
                                                    forKey: NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
```